# Using query in access (find the max in a row and display in new column)

Tags: mysql, ms-access

I have a table like this in MS access :

```
ID  Name     Date of Arrival
1   Apple    11/3/2014
2   Apple    10/5/2014
3   Orange   11/3/2014
4   Orange   
5   Grape    19/3/2014
6   Pear     20/3/2014
7   Pear     11/3/2014
8   Pear     09/3/2014
```

I am hoping to have a query that can add a column name "latest arrival" which store 1 if it is the latest arrival and 0 if not.

the result should be

```
ID  Name     Date of Arrival    Latest Arrival
1   Apple    11/3/2014          0
2   Apple    10/5/2014          1
3   Orange   11/3/2014          1
4   Orange                      0
5   Grape    19/3/2014          1
6   Pear     20/3/2014          1
7   Pear     11/3/2014          0
8   Pear     09/3/2014          0
```

Thank you very much for helping me out!

Answer (score 0):

You need two queries (or one query with a subquery if you're using VBA).  The first query gets the max date for each item

```
"select name, max([date of arrival]) as [max date] from arrival"
```

Then join that query (or use as a subquery) to

```
"select id, name, [date of arrival], iif([date of arrival] = [max date],1,0) as latest from (select name, max([date of arrival] from arrival)"
```

Let me know if you need a picture - I don't know if you're using VBA or the graphical interface.

Comment: If this answer has worked for you, can you put an accept on it? This helps give the answering user permissions to take on other activities. Yanks.